# Neo4j REST API - Index Node with multiple Properties

Tags: lucene, indexing, neo4j

I have multiple Nodes with a title, a subtitle and a text property. Now when I index them (index/node/pages/title/foo) I can only search for the title property. How do I index the other two properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the subtitle just the same way (index/node/pages/subtitle/bar) but for the text property you might want a fulltext index. Documentation on indexing is [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-indexes.html) and how to create a fulltext index is [there](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-create-node-index-with-configuration). At some point [batch operations](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-batch-ops.html) should make sense, but this feature is considered experimental so far.